# AMD Software: Adrenaline Edition Causing Blurry Text and HDMI Scaling Issues with Ryzen 3 3200G

Tags: windows, device-driver

Ever since I installed AMD Software: Adrenaline Edition on my AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics, I have been experiencing blurry text, HDMI scaling problems, and choppy graphics. Initially, the text looked fine, but after installing the software, blurriness appeared, and HDMI overscan became an issue.

To resolve the overscan problem, I adjusted the HDMI Scaling settings, which temporarily fixed the issue. However, upon the next boot, the display encountered underscan problems instead. Reverting the scaling back to 0% addressed the underscan, but on the subsequent boot, the overscan issue resurfaced.

Moreover, if I don't install the AMD software, the graphics appear choppy and performance suffers. As a result, I find myself having to adjust the HDMI Scaling every time I turn on my PC, which has become quite frustrating.

I'm seeking suggestions and solutions to tackle these AMD Software-related issues, including the choppiness in graphics when the software is not installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!